# SyntaxError in PostsController#index in ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have just started learning ruby on rails. I followed the guide on http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html.

`posts_controller.rb` file contains the following code

```
class PostsController < ApplicationController

def create
  @post = Post.new(post_params)

  if @post.save
    redirect_to @post
  else
    render 'new'
  end
end

def show
  @post = Post.find(params[:id])
end

def index
  @posts = Post.all
end

def edit
  @post = Post.find(params[:id])
end

def update
  @post = Post.find(params[:id])

  if @post.update(post_params)
    redirect_to @post
  else
    render 'edit'
  end
end

def destroy
  @post = Post.find(params[:id])
  @post.destroy

  redirect_to posts_path
end

private
  def post_params
    params.require(:post).permit(:title, :text)
  end
```

---

And my `app/views/posts/new.html.erb` file contains

```
<h1>New post</h1>
<%= form_for :post, url: posts_path do |f| %>
<% if @post.errors.any? %>
  <div id="error_explanation">
    <h2><%= pluralize(@post.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited
      this post from being saved:</h2>
    <ul>
    <% @post.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
      <li><%= msg %></li>
    <% end %>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <% end %>
  <p>
    <%= f.label :title %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :title %>
  </p>

  <p>
    <%= f.label :text %><br>
    <%= f.text_area :text %>
  </p>

  <p>
    <%= f.submit %>
  </p>
<% end %>
<%= form_for :post do |f| %>
  ...
<% end %>

<%= render 'form' %>

<%= link_to 'Back', posts_path %>
```

---

Also `app/views/posts/edit.html.erb` contains

```
<h1>Edit post</h1>

<%= form_for :post, url: post_path(@post), method: :patch do |f| %>
  <% if @post.errors.any? %>
  <div id="error_explanation">
    <h2><%= pluralize(@post.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited
      this post from being saved:</h2>
    <ul>
    <% @post.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
      <li><%= msg %></li>
    <% end %>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <% end %>
  <p>
    <%= f.label :title %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :title %>
  </p>

  <p>
    <%= f.label :text %><br>
    <%= f.text_area :text %>
  </p>

  <p>
    <%= f.submit %>
  </p>

<% end %>

<%= render 'form' %>

<%= link_to 'Back', posts_path %>
```

---

```
SyntaxError in PostsController#index
C:/Users/punitha/blog/app/controllers/posts_controller.rb:50: syntax error, unexpected end-of-input, expecting keyword_end

Rails.root: C:/Users/punitha/blog

Application Trace | Framework Trace | Full Trace
Request

Parameters:

None
Toggle session dump
Toggle env dump
Response

Headers:

none.
```

Comment: We dont need any view templates, the error is - as stated in the error message - in line 50 of your `posts_controller.rb`. The problem seems to be a missing `end` statement. Maybe you post your complete controller code - in the pasted code, everything seems to be fine.

Comment: please post the complete `posts_controller.rb` file.

Comment: You should post the entire `posts_controller.rb` file, not just the contents of the class. Fixing the indenting on the code might give you a clue as to where the missing `end` is.

Comment: Looks like you are missing the final 'end' to close the class statement - add 'end' to the end of the file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like a missing `end` at the very bottom of `posts_controller.rb`